# Image Classification when image is a plot of two functions

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, image-preprocessing

My goal is to perform a supervised classification of a number of objects. Each object is described by a plot of two functions, f(t) and g(t).

[image]

The plot dimensions, (b - a) and T, are about the same for each object and it looks like they can be normalized to (0, 1) and (0, 1).

Is this an image classification problem? I'm asking because most of the pixels are white.
Besides, all of the numeric coordinates on which the plots are based are known (we don't have to extract them from the images).

In any case, what method would you recommend for solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it is an image classification problem. Instead of plotting it, and using the plot as image, I would recommend you to use the values directly. You can think of them as 1D images with 2 channels. You can use 1D CNN based models for it. You might also want to check the models which are used to classify EEG signals, since they also deal with similar format of input data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.